# Infopath how to get curent element ID

Tags: infopath, item

How to get in infopath current element id ? I have got a list, and I always want to take last number id from list.

Comment: Are you trying to display some auto number on the form? Like the next ID that get assigned to the new item?

Comment: How could I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using following steps

1. In SharePoint, create a form library to submit your forms to.
2. In InfoPath, create a new (browser-compatible) InfoPath form template.
3. Add a Text Box control to the form template and name it autonumber.
4. On the Tools menu, click Data Connections.
5. On the Data Connections dialog box, click Add, and create a Receive data connection to the SharePoint library that you created in step 1. In step 5 of the data connection wizard, uncheck all fields and then check the ID field. In the last step of the data connection wizard, uncheck Automatically retrieve data when form is opened, name the data connection RetrieveIDs, and click Finish.
6. On the Data Connections dialog box, click Add, and create a Submit data connection to the SharePoint library that you created in step 1. In step 3 of the data connection wizard,  click the formula button behind the File name field.
7. On the Insert Formula dialog box, type max( and then click Insert Field or Group.
8. On the Select a Field or Group dialog box, select RetrieveIDs from the Data source drop-down list box, expand all the nodes, click ID, and then click OK.
9. On the Insert Formula dialog box, type ) + 1 and click OK.
10. On the Data Connection Wizard dialog box, the expression in the File name field should resemble:

    ```
    max(@ID) + 1
    ```
11. On the Data Connection Wizard dialog box, click Next, name the data connection Main submit, and then click Finish.
12. On the Data Connections dialog box, click Close.
13. On the Tools menu, click Submit Options.
14. On the Submit Options dialog box, check the Allow users to submit this form checkbox, select the Perform custom actions using rules option, click Advanced, select Close the form from the After submit drop-down list box, and then click Rules.
15. On the Rules dialog box, click Add.
16. On the Rule dialog box, add an Action that says:

    ```
    `Query using data connection: RetrieveIDs`
    ```
17. On the Rule dialog box, add a second Action that says:

    ```
     `Set a field's value: autonumber = max(@ID) + 1`
     Note: @ID is selected from the RetrieveIDs secondary data source in the same way you selected it in step 8.
    ```
18. On the Rule dialog box, add a third Action that says:

    ```
      Submit using data connection: Main submit
    ```
19. Click OK when closing all dialog boxes that are currently open.
20. Publish the form template to the library you created in step 1.

Source - http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/autonumber-infopath-form-submitted-sharepoint-library.htm

The above approach has an issue, because it relies on the ID value and we can't guarantee that people are not working con currently. To solve that you can take a look at this https://sharepointhacker.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/infopath-getting-the-sharepoint-item-id/